# Unable to populate datatable using ajax source

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I am unable to populate a datatable using ajax data source. I am using Codeigniter version 3 and WAMP v 3.2.0.
VIEW Code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" id="farmer_data_table">
   <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
             <th>Phone No.</th>
             <th>City/Town</th>
             <th>PIN</th>
             <th>State</th>
         </tr>
   </thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#farmer_data_table').DataTable( {
            "ajax": "<?=site_url();?>nautics/farmers/fetch_farmer_data/",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "first_name" },
                { "data": "gender" },
                { "data": "phone_number" },
                { "data": "city_town" },
                { "data": "pin_code" },
                { "data": "state" }
            ]
        } );
    });
```

Controller Code:

```
public function fetch_farmer_data()
{
    $url="http://<IP Address>/api/v1/form-data/all-record";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'x-access-token: ' . $this->session->userdata('access_token')
    ));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($response,true);
    //var_dump($result);
}
```

var_dump($result) shows data as:

```
array (size=1)
  'data' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=28)
          'active' => boolean true
          'address' => string 'Golghat,-' (length=9)
          'age' => int 27
          'alt_phone_number' => string '' (length=0)
          .................................more key-value pairs
      1 => 
        array (size=28)
          'active' => boolean true
          'address' => string 'Golaghat,-' (length=10)
          'age' => int 27
          'alt_phone_number' => string '' (length=0)
        .................................more key-value pairs
```

The error message is:

```
DataTables warning: table id=farmer_data_table - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Can anyone please tell me if my json data is in incorrect format or the entire code to populate datatable is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In controller code, you need to output the json. In the code, your ajax request is returning an empty page. Add echo $result;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the response as the output will do if the response is in json, so there is no need to encode or decode remove the line  $result = json_decode($response,true); completely in addition to what @alexktz has said and check

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller does not return something.

You are doing `$result = json_decode($response,true);` which creates the JSON, but the controller does not offer it to the request site.

You should have something like that after the line mentioned above:

```
return $this->output
            ->set_content_type('application/json')
            ->set_output($result);
```

Edit:

The line `$result = json_decode($response,true);` is also wrong, you have an Array, which you wanted to have converted to a JSON. So you have to use `json_encode` instead for the response.

Comment: Opps I forgot to write that. Thanks for reminding me. But now it shows "Array to string conversion" error.

Comment: There is another mistake, I updated my answer. You used "json_decode" instead of "json_encode".

Comment: I have done the changes that you mentioned but it still shows "Invalid JSON response" error.